# Singleton class not working with tab bar iphone application

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller, singleton

I have a tab-bar application, im using singleton class to share some data through out my application. In my application delegate class in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method I am getting my data from server and storing it in singleton class, and I can see that its been stored correctly in my singleton class using NSLog.

But now when, I am trying to access that data in my second tab-bar click its giving me “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
my viewDidLoad code

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

SingleTon *get = [SingleTon sharedInstanceHname];
result = [get getHname:result];
list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:result];
 NSLog(@"List%@", list);


[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I can see that error (“EXC_BAD_ACCESS”) is at line

```
 list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:result];
```

I want to use this data to populate in second tab bar view...any suggestions how to resolve this error????

sharedInstance method

```
 static SingleTon  *_sharedInstanceHname;

 - (id) init
 {
if (self = [super init])
{
    // custom initialization
    //memset(board, 0, sizeof(board));
    hname = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    index =1;
}
return self;
```

}

```
     + (SingleTon *) sharedInstanceHname   
      {
       if (!_sharedInstanceHname)
   {
    _sharedInstanceHname = [[SingleTon alloc] init];
    }

    return _sharedInstanceHname;
        } 



    - (NSMutableArray *) getHname:(NSMutableArray *)x
    {
return hname;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your `+sharedInstanceHname` method?

Comment: I have posted sharedInstanceHname method of my Singleton class in original question and result above in viewDidLoad is NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the message getHname returning?

I suspect the 'result' is not a member of NSArray.

Another thought is perhaps 'result' is nil. I don't think the method initWithArray: like been given a nil value.

Comment: result in null, but the reason of it being null i want to understand.

Comment: Then can you give more information of the previous line. Is hname initialised to something other than nil.

Comment: Yes its been initialized to default value ="hello" in my singleton class. Even then, could someone tell me reason of it being null as my singleton sharesInstance method is used to initialize hname in appdelegate class which I can see in Log.

Comment: Can I assume the initialisation is being done in the init? Also, _sharedInstanceHname is declared somewhere and initialised in the SingleTon implementation file as static SingleTon *_sharedInstanceHname = nil;

Comment: yes intilization is done in init...indeed...you can also see in my question initialization of static _sharedInstanceHname

Comment: 'you can also see in my question initialization of static _sharedInstanceHname' --- err... Sorry... where? The only place where 'static' is found it the page is in these comments.

Comment: It's not a good idea to initialise your static variable without a nil. I find compilers (and the weather) can randomly initialise this to not being nil at the outset. static SingleTon  *_sharedInstanceHname; It is possible this just points to some random memory!

Comment: Also, are you sure your code is not releasing the Singleton elsewhere? i.e. Have you overridden the retain, release (etc) methods to prevent a release? As per standard Objective C Singleton implementation.

Comment: Martinws: I am getting your point, but I was using the same singleton class previously in my view based application and it was working like charm in any view any where. Some how while i am using tab-bar application its not giving me results. Also, Iam not releasing Singleton elsewhere.

Comment: All I can go on is what you provide. If result is nil the array will crash and the only thing I see which is wrong is the  _sharedInstanceHname is not correctly initialised to nil. If you dont initialise it, then sometimes it will work correctly and other times it wont. Also make sure  hname is being released elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Do `sharedInstanceHname` or `gHname` return autoreleased objects? You may need to retain them for your use like so:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
   SingleTon *get = [SingleTon sharedInstanceHname];
   [get retain];
   result = [get gHname:result];
   [result retain];
   [get release];
   list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:result];
   [result release];

   [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

I wouldn't use the above code though; it serves only the purpose of demonstrating to you the concept of autorelease and retain/release ownership. Figure out what `sharedInstanceHname` or `gHname` return, and program accordingly.

EDIT: More importantly, does the `sharedInstanceHname` method in the SingleTon class retain ownership of the object returned by that method? If it does return an autoreleased object, it isn't strictly a Singleton object and rather a constructor of sorts.

Comment: Alan: I edited my original question with sharedinstanceHname method...could you please tell me what you mean by retaining ownership of object? you can help by seeing my code.